# Remove leading slash (/) from imports after bundling a Vite project

Tags: build, vite, rollup, slash

In my project, during dev everything works great but my target app seems to not parse imports that start with "/" properly ( I am developing for a local app, not for a website / webapp).
How can I get Vite to ommit the `/` at the beginning of import statements only when building?

For example, if I have a file in my `public` folder that I import like so:

`import something from '/file.svg`

I need it to bundle as:

`import something from 'assets/file.svg`

But instead I am getting:

`import something from '/assets/file.svg`

I have tried modifying `vite.config.js` to include any of the following:

- `base: ''`,
- `base: '/'`,
- `base: './'`,

Answer (score 0):

Check Vite version in your project. It seems there was an issue with `base` option in old versions.

<sup>I don't know the exact issue. But [this one](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/8202) is related to `base` option. And it was fixed in 2022.</sup>

**Update Vite and its plugins in your project and try again with empty string.** (value `./` also works according to the [Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options#base)).

Pay attention that you must specify the `base` option on top-level config object (NOT inside `build` option).

For example, this part of `vite.config.js` file demonstrates it:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  base: '',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  build: {...
```

For Vite version `5.1.5` installed on my machine I get this result HTML file in the output (`dist`) folder:

[image]